# How to read and print the content of PDF in python 2.7?

Tags: pdf, python

I used the PyPDF2 library , and open the pdf file

```
file = open("C:\\Users\\ZJ\\S40rooms.pdf",'rb')
```

what should i do know to read the content of the pdf ?
and i need to know all functions in PyPDF2 to use it later.

and also , about the searching in pdf by python 2.7 , I have a table inside the pdf .. and I need to split each column separately for search easily.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like howtos, manuals, [multi-media content](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185).

Answer (score 3):

PyPDF2 has a module called **PdfFileReader** so you will have to **import** that. I'm not sure whether you know the syntax for importing from an existing module so I'll include that.

**from** PyPDF2 **import** PdfFileReader

file = PdfFileReader(open("filePath", 'rb'))

Here is a rough list of methods

- addBlankPage-create a new page
- addBookmark-add a bookmark to the pdf
- addLink- add a link in a specific rectangular area
- addMetaData- add meta data to the pdf
- insertPage-adds a page at a specific index
- insertBlankPage-insert a blank page at a specific index
- addNamedDestination-add a named destination object to the page
- addNamedDestinationObject-add a created named destination to the page
- encrypt-encrypt the pdf (setting use_128bit to True creates 128 bit encryption and False creates 40 bit encryption with a default of 128 bits)
- removeLinks-removes links by object
- removeText-removes text by text object
  -setPageMode-set the page mode (e.g. /FullScreen,/UseOutlines,/UseThumbs,/UseNone)
- setPageLayout-set the layout(e.g./NoLayout,/SinglePage,/OneColumn,/TwoColumnLeft)
- getPage-get a page by index
- getLayout-get the layout
- getPageMode-get the page mode
- getOutlineRoot-get the root outline

  but you can find a more exhaustive list here [PyPDF2: the new fork in pyPdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/pythondoc-pyPdf.pdf.html) and sample code and demonstration code here [Manipulating PDF's with Python](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/11/pypdf2-the-new-fork-of-pypdf/)

I had more links but my reputation or lack thereof prevented me from posting them. Good luck!

**P.S** I almost forgot about the tables. Try a module called PANDAS, it's a very powerful module!

Comment: thank you so much :) , but about PANDAS .. It's same PyPDF2 ?

Comment: because i have a table content some informations inside the PDF , and the only things that I want to do it is searching in the table and display the informations.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what Pandas is for ;)

Comment: can you show my how can i use the pandas ? i just need to import pandas or must use pip to install it ?

Comment: Sorry I left you with it :( Yeah use pip and then import it like any other module. Once again sorry for leaving you with it, it wasn't my intention. Short attention span lol